Nuxt 3: Error page displays blank in production
I'm facing an issue with Nuxt 3. My application is running in SSR mode and deployed using Docker Compose, with Traefik managing the routing. In my local environment, the error.vue page displays correctly when I enter an invalid URL or when a error occurs (404, 500). When I run the app with yarn run dev, the error page shows up as expected. However, in production mode, when I execute node .output/server/index.mjs, the error page doesn't work and instead shows a blank page. I see a message in the logs, but I can't figure out the source of the issue. This error only occurs in production, not in development. I'm open to any ideas or suggestions.
frontend  | vue:error TypeError: nuxtApp.hook is not a function
frontend  |     at file:///app/.output/server/chunks/build/server.mjs:6874:11
frontend  |     at renderComponentRoot (/app/.output/server/node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.prod.js:5010:13)
frontend-antramy  |     at renderComponentSubTree (/app/.output/server/node_modules/@vue/server-renderer/dist/server-renderer.cjs.prod.js:401:16)
frontend  |     at renderComponentVNode (/app/.output/server/node_modules/@vue/server-renderer/dist/server-renderer.cjs.prod.js:394:12)
frontend  |     at ssrRenderComponent (/app/.output/server/node_modules/@vue/server-renderer/dist/server-renderer.cjs.prod.js:86:10)
frontend  |     at default (file:///app/.output/server/chunks/build/server.mjs:6912:19)
frontend  |     at ssrRenderSuspense (/app/.output/server/node_modules/@vue/server-renderer/dist/server-renderer.cjs.prod.js:224:5)
frontend  |     at file:///app/.output/server/chunks/build/server.mjs:6907:7
frontend  |     at renderComponentSubTree (/app/.output/server/node_modules/@vue/server-renderer/dist/server-renderer.cjs.prod.js:444:9)
frontend  |     at renderComponentVNode (/app/.output/server/node_modules/@vue/server-renderer/dist/server-renderer.cjs.prod.js:394:12) null https://vuejs.org/error-reference/#runtime-1


I have already started a discussion on GitHub, but I haven't received any response. That's why I'm bringing the issue here. Thank you in advance for your help.
